# Doubts regarding unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navigationbar

I want to display a cascaded unordered list as shown below:

```
   Home    Fixtures        Results    Leaderboard  
           Upcoming Week              Goals
           Month                      Assists
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Similar question was posted a couple of days ago, and it was already a dupe with the flexbox solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this,

```
<ul class="main-ul">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="inner-ul">
            <li>Fixtures</li>
            <li>Upcoming Week</li>
            <li>Month</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Results</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="inner-ul">
            <li>Leaderboard</li>
            <li>Goals</li>
            <li>Assists</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and css like below,

```
ul.main-ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
ul.main-ul>li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
ul.inner-ul>li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: You need at least 15 rep for that, atm. he can only accept your solution.